# Reverse Nodes in k-Group

Tags: javascript, reverse

Given this linked list: 1->2->3->4->5
k = 2, you should return: 2->1->4->3->5                                        I am not getting desired output can some one looked into where I am making mistake.

```
`class Node{
    constructor(val){
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    } }


class SinglyLinkedList{
    constructor(){
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }
       push(val){
        var newNode = new Node(val);
        if(!this.head){
            this.head = newNode;
            this.tail = this.head;

    } else {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            this.tail = newNode;
        }
        this.length++;
        return this;}


  reverseKGroup (head,k){  
  var count = 0;
  var  now =  head;
  var last = head;
  var tmp = null;

  if (!head || k < 2) return head;  
  while (now && count < k) {
    now = now.next;
    count++;
  }

  if (count === k) {
    reverseKGroup(this.now, k);
    while (count-- > 0) {
      tmp = last.next;
      last.next = now;
      now = last;
      last = tmp;
    }
    last = now;
  I need to implement interview problem ,
```

Given this linked list: 1->2->3->4->5

k = 2, you should return: 2->1->4->3->5
I am not getting desired output can some one looked into where I am making mistake.

```
class Node{
        constructor(val){
            this.val = val;
            this.next = null;
        } }


    class SinglyLinkedList{
        constructor(){
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
            this.length = 0;
        }
           push(val){
            var newNode = new Node(val);
            if(!this.head){
                this.head = newNode;
                this.tail = this.head;

        } else {
                this.tail.next = newNode;
                this.tail = newNode;
            }
            this.length++;
            return this;}


      reverseKGroup (head,k){  
      var count = 0;
      var  now =  head;
      var last = head;
      var tmp = null;

      if (!head || k < 2) return head;  
      while (now && count < k) {
        now = now.next;
        count++;
      }

      if (count === k) {
        reverseKGroup(this.now, k);
        while (count-- > 0) {
          tmp = last.next;
          last.next = now;
          now = last;
          last = tmp;
        }
        last = now;
      }
        console.log(last);
      return last;}

     }
```

Comment: We need to see your code to determine where the mistake is.

Comment: Thanks,  This was my first question figuring out how to post

Comment: it would be good if you can put some detailed description of code

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to first obtain the length of the list, then use that to determine which element will be the first in the rotated list. From there is it trivial to construct the rotated list.

The index of the first element of the rotated list is simply the length of the list modulo *k*, where *k* is the number of rotations. Convert the linked list to a plain-old Javascript array to obtain its length, and you're off to the races:

```js
var rotateRight = function(head, k) {
    // if empty list, do nothing
    if (!head) {
        return head;
    }

    // determine actual number of rotations
    let array = toArray(head);
    let length = array.length;
    let rotations = k % length;

    // if no rotations are required, return the original list
    if (rotations == 0) {
        return head;
    }

    let newHead = null;
    let first = null;

    // construct the rotated list
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        let index = ((length - rotations) + i) % length;
        let temp = new ListNode(array[index]);

        if (newHead) {
            newHead.next = temp;
        }
        else {
            first = temp;
        }

        newHead = temp;
    }

    return first;
};

// converts the linked list to an array so that we can find the length easily
function toArray(head) {
    let array = [];

    while(head) {
        array.push(head.val);
        head = head.next;
    }

    return array;
}
```

(I'm sure there is some recursive solution that is more efficient/elegant than this, but this works)

Tested on LeetCode:
[image]